# Why would Blender slow down in editmode with only 2886 vertices?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, performance

Blender slows down in edit mode with only 2886 vertices. I am not sure what is wrong with the file. Can someone suggest a solution to this?

My PC specs are:
Processor: Intel(R) corei7 3.50ghz
Ram 16gb
NVIDIA Geforce GTX 660Ti

[image]

Comment: perhaps your software expects more performance from your hardware knowing the year you're living in ;-) <br> Maybe some modifier is set to show up in the edit mode, maybe if you use the multitexture instead of GLSL it will become more agile.

Comment: Try downloading v2.79b
If that doesn't help. I'd recommend disabling any addons that do not come as default within blender. I've had problems with this before. lastly I would suggest turning down the undo steps and rasing the autosave interval.

Comment: Thx to mechanic, your suggestions help.  Since i just start, im not about to invest more for a while.  Can you recommend more tricks to lower requirements during editing mode?  As well as a reasonable Gcard?

Comment: Thx for your suggestion Delagone. Installing 2.79b didnt help.  I guess its my cheap spec lol.